# OpenLayers 3 - zoom to a selected feature

Tags: openlayers

I am working with OpenLayers 3. I used a dropdown menu to select a feature and I would like to zoom to the extent of the selected feature.  At the moment, it is possible to select by the dropdown menu but not to zoom. Is there any way to fix this?

```
    function selectByDivision(){ 
            var divisionUser = document.getElementById('division-select').options[document.getElementById('division-select').selectedIndex].text;


            var selectedFeatures = select.getFeatures();                                
            selectedFeatures.clear();               
            var features = lyr_divisions3857.getSource().getFeatures();

            if(features){
                  for(i=0;i<features.length;i++){
                                            if(features[i].get('DIVISION')==divisionUser){                                              

                                                        feature= features[i];                                                                                                                   
                                                        selectedFeatures.push(feature);                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                //map.zoomToExtent(features[i].getDataExtent());

                                                        var polygon = selectedFeatures.getFeatures();
                                                        var extent = polygon.getGeometry();

                                                        var size = (map.getSize());
                                                        view.fit(
                                                        extent,
                                                        size
                                                        );

                                                        map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());                                                                                                               
                                                        }
                                                    }                                                                           
                            }                                                                                                                                           
                        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Using [`fit`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html#fit) will set the view of the map to fit the geometry being used.

```
map.getView().fit(feature.getGeometry(), map.getSize())
```

Answer (score 5):

First thing first, let's make the concept clear:

I assume, your `select` variable holds a reference to an instance of `ol.interaction.Select`. If you call its `getFeatures` method, you will get an `ol.Collection` object holding your selected features internally. It is absolutely valid to call methods on it like `clear`, or `push`.

However, collection objects do not have a `getFeatures` method. To get the internal array the collection is holding, you have to call its `getArray` method instead:

```
var polygon = selectedFeatures.getArray();
```

Which returns a simple array. Now I assume, your function makes sure, this collection can only hold one member at the time you access it. An array though is an array with only one member, too, therefore you must access it with an index value:

```
var extent = polygon[0].getGeometry();
```

Now that you grabbed a reference to a geometry object correctly, it is still an instance of `ol.geom.Geometry`, not an extent (an array with four coordinates). As the method `fit` needs an extent, you can calculate it from the geometry with its `getExtent` method. Thus, you have to modify your line like this:

```
var extent = polygon[0].getGeometry().getExtent();
```

**UPDATE:**

You can call `fit` with a geometry object, therefore calculating the geometry's extent is not necessary.

Comment: What should be done in case of multiple features inside select interaction? So there are 10 features selected on the map, then how should we suppose to zoom to that extent?

Comment: found solution to zoom to extent of features as well. This is how its done
var extent = features[0].getGeometry().getExtent().slice(0);
features.forEach(function(feature){ ol.extent.extend(extent,feature.getGeometry().getExtent())});

source:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018786/openlayers-3-get-extent-of-all-feature-contents-in-a-list